# Horizontally center an absoluted element without fixed width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an absolute element align in the middle without a fixed width, this is I've tried:

```
.rm-line {
    background-color: #CCC;
    height: 4px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.rm-line span {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 0 10px;
    top: -4px;  
}
```

Demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2WNPm/). As you can see in the demo, the text is not centered, I need this to be centered at any text width, even if the text has more or less characters, it should align in the middle.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that using relative/absolute positioning isn't a requirement..

You should use `display: inline-block` on your `span` instead of `position: absolute`. The `span` will be centered by `text-align: center` on the `div`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/2WNPm/12/

Comment: Since you're only using left/right `padding`, you don't even need to add `display: inline-block` - the default of `inline` works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/2WNPm/29/

Comment: Cheers. That helped a lot. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
 .rm-line span {

     background-color: #FFF;
     padding: 0 10px;
     top: -4px;    
    margin:auto;
    display:block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but in Firefox it seems to work as desired if you set the span-box position to relative:

```
.rm-line span {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 0 10px;
    top: -4px;
}
```